# Is it better idea to call API endpoint on each delete if I have multiple records in array?

Tags: angularjs, frontend, backend

What exactly I am doing is, In contact list I have put a multiple contacts delete option. so when user press the delete button in background angular runs a code in loop and delete it from the contact's array. so my question is, is it better idea to call API in loop on each contact to delete the contact on server or should I send the contacts combined and then call API endpoint and after the response delete it on UI. which one is better ?

Comment: for deleting the contacts by each API call or submit the whole array of contacts.

Comment: For _deleting_ it doesn't matter: contacts are going to be deleted either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to send an array of users ids

If you do a loop, you gonna have a multiple api calls => it's not optimized

You have to think about offline first approach, and then users sometimes can't have a good internet

Comment: but what if I don't get a response after deleting it on server, the records will not delete on UI. this is also the case.

Comment: You have to use a http interceptor to intercept the response (for example if it's 404 you'll show a toaster error). The problem is if the user select for example 7 users, and the 3 requests were successful but the rest not. do you'll show a toaster error for each user ? :)

Comment: but is it better way to call it on each delete or it should a call with multiple records

Comment: I had this problem, there's no perfect solution, but I think if you send one request with multiple records gonna be better than sending multiple requests. You'll economize code, time and performance. Hope that helps you

Comment: I would send a list of id's and then you could back the transaction out if something bad happened..